# J3D flickering after applying 3D rotation and translation to an object

Tags: java, 3d, flicker, java-3d

I am working with a 3D application connected to a physical device. The 3D reprensentation should match the rotation and position of the device in the real world.

When it comes to its position, it's ok. I am having problems when I also apply the rotation.

I am using a gyroscope on the device and I am updating the scene at ~20FPS.

Here is the code for the update:

```
    public void updateRotation(int[] rollAngles){

    if(rollAngles.length>0){

        Transform3D newRotX = new Transform3D();
        newRotX.rotX(Math.toRadians(rollAngles[0]));

        Transform3D newRotY = new Transform3D();
        newRotY.rotY(Math.toRadians(rollAngles[1]));

        Transform3D newRotZ = new Transform3D();
        newRotZ.rotZ(Math.toRadians(rollAngles[2]));

        Transform3D transVec = new Transform3D();
        transVec.setTranslation(new Vector3f(curr_x,curr_y,0.0f));

        newRotX.mul(newRotY);
        newRotX.mul(newRotZ);
        newRotX.mul(transVec);


        sphereGroup.setTransform(newRotX);
    }
}
```

What happens is that the object jumps around the screen: first at some "random" place and then to the actual X,Y,Z coordinate.

Any idea on this?

P.S. Also, sometimes the 3D scene disappears completely and I have to click and drag on it to be able to see it again. Is it a common issue? How do I solve it?

Comment: It looks as if it would be the accelerometer itself passing high values for whatever reason. You may need to apply some sort of smoothing to reduce the effect.

Comment: I am already doing this:  if(data > 1000 || data < -1000)   data = 0; The problem is the transformation with the rotation. The X,Y,Z translation itself is for sure ok.